# How Can I Generate value for key address with consol.table

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, javascript-objects

Please Help Me,..

This is main function[image: main function]

code function ListingNViews
[image]

console

[image]

here Ouput
[image: Output]

in this output my mistake is.. i can't show value to field address in consol.table ..
Plese Help Me Sir.

Comment: What is `fieldOfListing` when `listingNViews` is called?

Comment: **fieldOfListing** it just name of parameter,

Comment: So, `fieldOfListing` is an optional parameter to `listingNViews`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: yupss..!! why address output not show when i use Console.table... please help me..  you might solved it..